# How to get include preg_match_all results in header location?

Tags: header, location, preg-match-all

I have the following function written in function.php in a wordpress theme

```
function get_mms($my_post) {
            $post_id = $my_post; //$_GET["p"];
            $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
            $title = $queried_post->post_title;

            preg_match_all('#\[mms\](.+)\[\/mms\]#', $queried_post->post_content, $matches);
            echo 'EN: ' . $matches[1][0];



            echo '<br><br><form action= " ' . get_permalink( $id ) . ' " method="post">
    Numar: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input name="submito" type="submit" />
    </form>'; 

    $numero = $_POST["fname"];

    if(isset($_POST['submito'])&& $_POST['fname']){
    $numero = $_POST["fname"];
    header("Location: http://server/&to=$numero&text='.$matches[1][0].'&from=Moldcell");
    }
```

When I submit the form instead of getting the value of  `$matches[1][0]` I get `Array[0]`.

Is there someting I did wrong? What can I do to make it grab the value of `preg_match_all` results?